# get error No operations allowed after connection closed

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

I develop application in google app engine and cloud sql 
I write the server with java jpa eclipselink.
every day for a few minutes I get this exception:
"No operations allowed after connection closed"
and after few more minutes the exception disappear
how I can resolve the exception

Yes I was googling this exception but did not found an answer

attached is my stack trace

```
exception:Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services 
- 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): 
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException 
(LoggerHelper.java:20)
Internal Exception: 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: 
No operations allowed after connection closed.
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT users.*, organizationUsers.id as 
managementOrganizationUserId, 
organizationUsers.managementOrganizationId,organizationUsers.userId 
FROM ManagementOrganizationUsersTable as organizationUsers LEFT JOIN 
UsersTable as users  ON(users.id=organizationUsers.userId AND 
users.userRoleType=?) WHERE 
organizationUsers.managementOrganizationId=? AND users.userRoleType=? 
GROUP BY 
organizationUsers.id,organizationUsers.managementOrganizationId, 
organizationUsers.userId ORDER BY firstName  ASC  LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: ResultSetMappingQuery(sql="SELECT users.*, 
organizationUsers.id as 
managementOrganizationUserId, 
organizationUsers.managementOrganizationId,organizationUsers.userId 
FROM ManagementOrganizationUsersTable as organizationUsers LEFT JOIN 
UsersTable as users  ON(users.id=organizationUsers.userId AND 
users.userRoleType=?) WHERE 
organizationUsers.managementOrganizationId=? AND users.userRoleType=? 
GROUP BY 
organizationUsers.id,organizationUsers.managementOrganizationId, 
organizationUsers.userId ORDER BY firstName  ASC  LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0")
```

"What are your connection settings"

```
<properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="XXXX" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="XXXX" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
        <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.node2.max" value="32"/>
    </properties>
```

"Are your network connections killed in your datasource after inactivity"
 I dont understand the question
Thank you

Comment: Did you try googling the exception message?

Comment: whats the exception stack trace show? What are your connection settings?  Are your network connections killed in your datasource after inactivity?

Comment: I edited my question Thank you